# Cheapest and easiest ways to level my lawn

Tags: lawn, landscaping

I bought this house 2 years ago, and one annoying aspect of it is that the garden 'slopes' towards the rear - see below

[image: My uneven garden]

This is becoming a problem now as I want to build a climbing frame for my son in that area, which will require a flat surface. What would be the simplest way of leveling this? Open to 'outside of the box' ideas too!

Comment: How steep is the gradient,  or how much lower is the bottom than the top? Is  the top end level with the house? Will you be removing the concrete  (if that's what it is) path to avoid harm from falling off the frame? I note you're in Cardiff  so does it  ever flood or stay very soggy at  the lower end? How big is the garden (length and  width)?

Comment: You should also take your neighbors into consideration, as any grade changes on your lot will most likely change how water drains off of and into their lots. If you raise your yard, where will rainwater drain to?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the easiest way would be to go rent a bobcat and remove the excess dirt. My "out of the box" idea would be to stabilize the frame of your climbing wall with rebar that has been driven into the ground rather than allowing gravity to stabilize the structure. However, I like the idea of removing the dirt and starting with a flat surface better. Either way you have some problems. If you remove the dirt then there will be a gap between the ground and the fence and if you use the rebar approach then you will have to do a lot more measuring when you build the wall.

Then of course there is the option of trying to find some cheap dirt. If your lucky, you might find someone who has recently excavated a property who doesn't want the dirt. They might even pay YOU to take the dirt off their hands.

Answer (score 0):

Find your highest point & remove the dirt to bring back to the lowest point. Rotavate the bottom end & rake down to the lower part towards the house